# What's the name of this green fruit with little pikes fallen from a city tree on the pavement?

Tags: species-identification, trees, fruit

What's the name of this green fruit with little pikes fallen from a tree on Paris (France) pavement ?

[image: Fruit]
[image: Tree]

Comment: Seems horse chestnut.

Comment: It would be very  helpful to know the location of the photo (city, country).

Comment: Also something idea of the size.

Comment: Its 100% a euro or an indian conker tree species.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Identifications questions should include: 1) one or more clear closeup photos of the organism (photos from multiple angles if possible) — in this case clear pictures of the leaves and bark of the tree; and 2) an estimate of the size of the tree and the fruit. Please [edit] your post to include this essential information. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site, which differs from the SE sites that you are more familiar with. Thanks! 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is horse chestnut it is very common to plant chestnut trees in public parks and a lot of people do have them around their property and by the side of many roads.

What you have in your picture is the fruit and the leaves on the ground confirms that this is horse chestnut.

Source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesculus_hippocastanum

The nut is poisonus and the toxin can cause loss of coordination and tremors in horses if they eat the nuts.

Touching or handling the nuts do not cause any adverse effect to humans they are only dangerous to humans if they are eaten.

Horse chestnut contains alcaloid saponins and glucosides that have a toxic effect on mamals.